HP Function to Match Probability of Grouped Players in a Turn-Based Game
Once a week, the boys and I have movie night where we each suggest a movie, and one is chosen randomly. Usually, each movie has an equal chance of being picked (e.g., 1/4 if there are four movies). But if two people choose the same movie, the odds shift (e.g., 2/4 for that movie and 1/4 for the others) in order to keep it fair.
To make things interesting, I coded a “battle” (basically D&D) in pygame. Each movie begins with 100hp. The movie list is randomized, and then each movie has a turn. On each turn, the movie randomly selects a target from the remaining movies. It picks a random value between 1-20 and subtracts that from the target’s health. If the target’s health is less than or equal to zero, it is removed from the list.
This works fine if every person puts up their own movie, but sometimes two or more of us want to back the same one. So the question is, How much HP does a grouped-up movie need to ensure that its probability of winning fairly reflects the number of people backing it?
I assumed in order to double the odds, the HP would need to double, or it would be some clean result like 200, 150, 141, etc. But the required HP for fairness is actually much less.
I used simulations to find the required HP. Here’s the approximate HP needed for different group sizes:
3 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118

4 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118
•   3: 118

5 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118
•   3: 129
•   4: 123

6 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118
•   3: 130
•   4: 137
•   5: 127

7 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118
•   3: 129
•   4: 138
•   5: 143
•   6: 130

8 Players
•   1: 100
•   2: 118
•   3: 129
•   4: 138
•   5: 144
•   6: 148
•   7: 132

The only way I have right now to figure out how much HP to give a grouped-up movie is by changing its HP value in simulations until its probability of winning reaches the expected result.
Is there a way to derive a formula that figures this out? I know it must depend on how much damage is applied (1-20 in this case) and on the total number of players vs how many are grouping up, but I really have no idea where to start.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you have solved the problem when there are no duplicate choices I think you can get a fair result by using your lottery to choose the person whose movie is chosen. That should double the chances for a movie that two people recommend.

Oh ok so you’re saying if you have 4 people and 3 movies, just duplicate the movie so it shows up twice and the chance of it being picked will double? I guess that is the simplest answer. But I am also interested in if there is a way to keep it at 3 movies with 2 people backing it and what the HP of that movie would then have to be.

I suspect there is no clean way to solve the problem by reverse engineering the hit points.
